# Desktop file not working in Ubuntu Unity, unless it is executable which breaks packaging guidelines

Tags: ubuntu, debian, deb, ubuntu-unity, lintian

In unity, icons will only be displayed when the .desktop file has executable permissions. But doing this causes lintian to complain with `executable-desktop-file`. What am I supposed to do in this instance?

Comment: Are you trying to make changes to the desktop manager code? If you are just trying to change the configuration settings without changing the code, then you should ask on SuperUser.com, ubuntu.stackexchange.com, or unix.stackexchange.com. StackOverflow is only for programming questions.

Answer (score 3):

After creating a shortcut, I use the following syntax without problem :

```
sudo desktop-file-install /usr/share/applications/your_file.desktop
```

Ubuntu 14.04 + Unity.

Regards, Stéphane.